# App modal File dialogs on windows

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

How do i make the common File dialogs App modal using Common File Dialog API ? The dialogs come up modal with respect to the owner window. I want to block all the process' windows when a file dialog is up. In my current code, I am disabling all windows belonging to the app except the dialog parent and when the dialog is closed I enable them again. There should be a better/easy way of achieving application wide modality with Common File Dialogs. Please let me know if there is a standard solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually disabling and re-enabling is the only way I know of in Windows.

The traditional model for Windows applications is to have a single top-level window per instance.  (Remember MDI apps?) Of course, there are exceptions, and many apps have always had floating tool palette windows.  Nevertheless, the disable-the-parent model works for the lion's share of applications, and it's possible for many-window apps to do what you're doing with manually disabling the extra windows.  Thus there isn't much demand for a more general solution.

If you wanted to re-architect things, you could have a master window that owns all the other top-level windows, and make the modal window use the master as a parent, but then you'd have to solve other problems related to the task bar, z-order, and positioning of the modal window.